# dnu restore fails on C# class library with "ambiguous" error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnu

I am running Visual Studio 2015 and trying to add a simple class library, NettlesLibrary.xproj, into a solution that uses the latest MVC.  I am unable to get the references working so I'm trying to run:

```
dnu restore
```

in the NettlesLibrary directory.

The error I get is:

```
CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\nettles3\src\NettlesLibrary\project.json
----------
System.InvalidOperationException: The project name 'NettlesLibrary' is ambiguous between the following projects:
C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\nettles3\src\NettlesLibrary
C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\nettles3\wrap\NettlesLibrary
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Where is your global.json? DNU will walk back up the tree looking for a project.json and then use that for paths, etc. You should probably put it in `~\Projects\nettles3` and then have entries in `Projects` for `src` and `wrap`. I just spent a couple of hours working this out - it's not intuitive.